# Tensorflow Installation Succeeded but Not Working

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, keras

> [libprotobuf FATAL
>   google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:67] This program
>   requires version 3.3.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the
>   installed version is 3.0.0.  Please update your library.  If you
>   compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from
>   the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. 
>   (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>         what():  This program requires version 3.3.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.0.0.  Please
>   update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure
>   that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as
>   your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in
>   "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
>       Aborted (core dumped)

I installed tesorflow for my Ubuntu machine, cpu version. Installation went smoothly. But when I do:

```
import tensorflow
```

I get the above error. I have tried reinstalling protobuf but nothing is working.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please specify which version of Ubuntu you are running, which version of TensorFlow, which python (2.7, 3.x).

It would also help to know how you installed TF. 

I would recommend installing anaconda, creating an environment with desired python version, then trying to install TensorFlow in the anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you protobuf version is 3.0.0, not match the 3.3.0. I would suggest uninstalling protobuf and installing the required protobuf version, or upgrade it. You can also refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2903) and [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1264)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your linux system has has PIP installed. Then in your main.py file try importing tensor flow as tf

Install up to date PIP:

`sudo zypper install python-pip python-setuptools python-wheel`

In your python file:

```
    import tensor flow as tf
```

Then refer to tensor flow as tf.

If that doest work:

```
    sudo apt-get remove --purge libprotobuf10 libprotobuf-dev
```